# Lesscss: Why spin(#000,180) is returning #000?

Tags: less

I need to know how to get the inverse color by lesscss.

Example: I have #000, i need #FFF.

And i need the detail explanation of spin(). And necessary links where i can see a color wheel where i can understand how spin() works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why it is not working as you expect

The `spin()` function only deals with *hue* (color), ***not*** *value* (grey scale changes are a value change). Take a look at [Figures 9 and 10 on this page](http://www.ncsu.edu/scivis/lessons/colormodels/color_models2.html) from North Carolina State University's site. Those figures help show the difference. The `spin()` function is rotating only in the two dimensional space of the hue circle of color, not *along* the *axis* of the third dimensional space dealing with saturation; i.e. the gray scale itself, which is what differentiates white from black, both of which have no *color* saturation).

This is why [on the LESS site we read](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-functions-spin) of `spin()` (emphasis added):

> Note that colors are passed through an RGB conversion, which doesn't
>   retain hue value for greys (*because hue has no meaning when there is
>   no saturation*)

And

> Colors are always returned as RGB values, so applying spin to a grey
>   value will do nothing.

### Getting what you want (Color Inversion)

See @seven-phases-max's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The [`spin`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-functions-spin) function changes the [Hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) property of a colour. Shades of grey (incl. white and black) are achromatic colours (i.e. they have the same "undefined" hue value).
To simply invert a colour use either [`difference`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-functions-difference) function:

```
difference(white, @colour)
```

or the simple colour [arithmetic](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations):

```
(#fff - @colour)
```